# USB enclosure that will work with a Western Digital WD20EARS 2TB SATAII 64MB Cache Hard Drive?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, enclosures

Wondering if there is a case that I can hook up one Western Digital WD20EARS 2TB SATAII 64MB Cache 
Hard Drive and use it as it is external USB hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Any SATA/USB enclosure should be just as capable of handling this hard drive as it is any other, provided the interfaces and physical size specifications are compatible.